# I need to convert a String to Blob within a Flow for the VersionData field on a ContentNote/ContentVersion type

Tags: visual-workflow, string, contentversion, blob, contentnote

I'm trying to insert a File (ContentVersion) or ContentNote with Rich Text within a Flow.

But has anyone encountered the need to convert a string to a blob (base64 encoded type) in order to get a ContentVersion.VersionData to insert properly?

I know I could use an *@InvokableApex* method, but I was worried I might be overengineering this. So please let me know if I'm missing something simple...

There has to be a way out of the box Salesforce to allow the insertion of a ContentNote with Rich Text, right?

[image: screenshotOfFlowError]

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you're very probably not missing anything. Formulas don't have any way to convert to or from base64, which would be the minimum requirement to have a chance of this working. As such, an InvocableMethod is probably the right choice.

Comment: I would like to know how were you able to insert Content Version's Version data using flow. Could you please share the SS of the complete flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of creating a *ContentVersion* Record, I'm able to create a *ContentNote* combined with a *ContentDocumentLink* without any issue at all.

My problem is I didn't have 'Enable Notes' turned on in *Notes Settings* in order to see *ContentNote*.

[image]